# How to find the images of u and v under T?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -4 & -8 \\
8 & -7 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}_.$

Define the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ by $T(x) = Ax$.

Let $u = \begin{bmatrix}
-2\\
1\\
2\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $v = \begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b\\
c\\
\end{bmatrix}_.$

Find the images of $u$ and $v$ under $T$.

I'm not sure exactly how to do this. What do they mean by find the images? Can someone help me out?

Comment: Just apply the operator $T$ to the vectors $u$ and $v$. The image of a vector under an operator is the vector one obtains by applying the operator to the starting vector.

Comment: What do you mean by "Just apply the operator $T$ to the vectors $u$ and $v$" .. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If you have an example, I'm sure I could mimic it.

Comment: It is nothing but matrix-vector multiplication. Just google it and open the wikipedia page

Comment: Oh cool, I see now. Thanks man!

Comment: So in the case of the image for $u$ under $T$ you would "plug in" $u$ into the equation for $T$, which is $T(u)=Au $. Then you just have to multiply the vector $u$ by the matrix $A$ to obtain its image. Repeat for $v$.

Comment: Cheers, glad to be of help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "the image of $u$ under $T$" refers to $T(u) = Au$. All that you have to do is multiply the matrix by the vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out this was simple matrix multiplication. 
$T(u) = \begin{bmatrix}
-18\\
-15\\
\end{bmatrix}$ and $T(v) = \begin{bmatrix} -a-4b-8c\\8a-7b+4c\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider projecting a $3D$ object on a $2D$ surface. (Just like a shadow of an object). Image means the projection of the object (here a set of vectors) from $\mathbb{R}^3$ **on** $\mathbb{R}^2$.. So the projection matrix(also known as the operator , since it operates on vectors) being given, therefore multiply each of the vectors$(\in \mathbb{R}^3)$ with $T$ to get their image (projection) on $\mathbb{R}^2$

So if $v_1$ and  $v_2$ are the vectors, their **images** will be $Tv_1$ and $Tv_2$ respectively.